# How to draw more than 50 google charts on the same page without freezing browser after live update

Tags: google-visualization

Data is updated live with socket.io.
In situations where is lot of updates in the same time browser freezes for several seconds.

I am updating data with .setValue command and then redraw chart with .draw.

Every chart has the same structure with different data...

```
data.addRows([
            [5,   null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [10,  null, null, 1, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, 1, null, null, null],
            [15,  null, null, 1, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, 1, null, null, null],
            [20,  null, null, 1, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, 1, null, null, null],
            [25,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [30,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [35,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [40,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [45,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [50,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [55,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [60,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],   
            [65,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [70,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [75,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [80,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [85,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null],
            [90,  null, null, null, null, null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, 'stroke-width: 0;', null, null, null, null, null, null]
          ]);
```

Comment: This is a javascript problem, and not specific to google charts?

Try working with javascript Workers when making the changes to the data and pass it back and forth in JSON strings, this will reduce at least a bit of the pressure on the User thread. 

W3 schools like for [workers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)

Comment: You can also use timeouts to break the updates up and keep the execution of updates from completely locking everything up.

Comment: For speed improvement it is better to initialize a DataTable by passing a JavaScript string literal object into the data parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is javascript problem and not specific to google charts.
I ended up with this solution:

```
 socket.on("notification", function (data) {
    for (var k = 0, len = data.length; k < len; k++) {
        var value = data[k];
        var delay_time = 0;
        var max_rows_to_process = 400;
        var current_block_number = Math.floor(k/max_rows_to_process);
        if (current_block_number) {
                delay_time = current_block_number * 1000;
            }
        doSetTimeOutDrawChart(value.chart_id, value.new_chart_data, delay_time);
   }
 }
 function doSetTimeOutDrawChart(chart_id, new_chart_data, delay){
    setTimeout(function () { 
        change_data_table_for_chart_and_redraw(chart_id, new_chart_data);
    }, delay);
  }
```